# How to download php generated zip/rar file with file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have small issue with php `file_get_contents();`
i try to download compressed packages from url like "http://mydomain.com?download.php?id=1234"
downloading same file with browser works and all headers seems to be ok but through file_get_contents file is empty...

Comment: Is the site doing the downloading the same as the site hosting the file?

Comment: does the download.php do a redirect to the .zip file?

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean that it return false ?

Anyway if you're download files, it would be better to use the curl library and the HTTP extension.

---

**Resources :**

- [php.net - curl examples](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)
- [php.net - http extension](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php)

Answer (score 0):

different host and mimetype returns empty so i can't hadle those packages.

- just installed http and got more information about link and yes it is redirected so is file_get_contents only way to go or does curl support redirection?

**Got it**

Found script from http://w-shadow.com/blog/2008/07/05/how-to-get-redirect-url-in-php/ which got me through with redirect link issue so now i got good script to fetch data.

Thank you all