# Beginner help need for simple PHP script

Tags: php

I'm a complete beginner in php (and a first 'poster' here on SO) and seem to be missing something in a small script that I am doing from a tutorial.

What the script is basically suppose to do is get Ticker names from a hosted txt file on the server and output historical prices fetched from yahoo finance.

Everything seems to be working fine except that the content that i get from the getCSVfile function is incorrect (I get the html from the yahoo error page). The fetched URL is however correct and if I type in the targeted URL manually everything works just fine.

It is probably a basic mistake but can't seem to find it. Seems to be related to '' and ""s.

Many thanks in advance for the help
Y

```
<?php 

include("includes/connect.php");

function createURL($ticker){
    $currentMonth = date('n') - 1;
    $currentDay = date('j');
    $currentYear = date('Y');
    $result = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv? s='.$ticker.'&a=07&b=19&c=2012&d=11&e=08&f=2012 &g=d&ignore=.csv';
    return (string)$result;
}

function getCSVFile($url, $outputFile){
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $content = str_replace('Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close','',$content);
    $content = trim($content);
   echo $content; /debugging
  file_put_contents($outputFile,$content);
}

//test debugging - this is where the problem seems to be happening - 
//the URL output is correct as is the getCSVfile but the combination of the two doesnt  work properly//

$test = createURL('GOOG');
echo $test;
getCSVFile($test, "memory.txt");

/code continues...

?>
```

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: You copy-pasted the $test-URL in the browser and it returns the correct result?

Comment: Yes, I've echoed the test URL in the browser and its the correct one.

Comment: Then start with the minimal thing: `$test = "your_correct_url"; echo file_get_contents($url);` If this works, but `$test = createURL('GOOG'); echo file_get_contents($url);` does not, then `"your_correct_url"` and `"createURL('GOOG')` are different.

Comment: Have you tried it using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php). This post might help too [file_get_contents on downloadable files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729583/how-to-download-php-generated-zip-rar-file-with-file-get-contents)

Comment: @NandakumarV the file_get_contents function actually does work if I paste in the url but does not when used with createURL

Comment: Then the strings are really different and it is your task to find out. Where. Maybe use var_dump instead of echo, to see also trailing spaces and so. Also keep in mind, that browsers might do some conversion on the process, to remove obvious errors (like trailing spaces and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your URL does contain a few spaces which do not belong in there:

```
$result = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv? s='.$ticker.'&a=07&b=19&c=2012&d=11&e=08&f=2012 &g=d&ignore=.csv';
                                                     ^                                               ^
```

Try

```
$result = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s='.$ticker.'&a=07&b=19&c=2012&d=11&e=08&f=2012&g=d&ignore=.csv';
```

instead.

To notice this kind of error, it is always the best way to copy'n'paste your debug output in the browser, not type it in -- otherwise you will often miss these small, obvious errors.

Comment: Apologies but those spaces where just added while editing my questions in the form above. They're not however on the inital script.

Comment: At the end of the day, you were right it was a stupid matter of spaces !! Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try using urlencode before returning the URL in your createURL function. So the code of that function would be something like this

```
function createURL($ticker){
$currentMonth = date('n') - 1;
$currentDay = date('j');
$currentYear = date('Y');
$result = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv? s='.$ticker.'&a=07&b=19&c=2012&d=11&e=08&f=2012 &g=d&ignore=.csv';
return urlencode($result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However urlencode has added % everywhere in the targeted URL, so can't seem to make it work this way.

Comment: `urlencode` will also encode characters like /,&,?: and turn this whole thing into something which is not nearly an URL anymore. `urlencode` is intended to encode things which later add as a parameter to the url, so they don't conflict with things like &, which are for parameter separation.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the hint.But adding urlencode gives the following error : file_get_contents(http%3A%2F%2Fichart.finance.yahoo.com%2Ftable.csv%3Fs%3DGOOG%26a%3D07%26b%3D19%26c%3D2012%26d%3D11%26e%3D08%26f%3D2012+%26g%3Dd%26ignore%3D.csv) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream:

Comment: Thats right @cebewee. So try using urlencode for the $ticker variable before adding it to the $result.
`code` $result = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv? s='.urlencode($ticker).'&a=07&b=19&c=2012&d=11&e=08&f=2012 &g=d&ignore=.csv';

Comment: @juanreyesv In general, this is a good idea. However, it is irrelevant for this example, as `urlencode('GOOG') == 'GOOG'`.

Comment: @cebewee if tried your test and indeed in does work with 'my correct url' passed in but not with createURL('GOOG'). What strange however is that echo createURL('GOOG') gives the correct URL (tried to copy and paste it in the browser and it does work).

Comment: @user1887478 Ok, you can also try changing a little bit your getCSVfile function. You can always try with CURL. Here is an example:

`function get_url_contents($url){
        $crl = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $ret = curl_exec($crl);
        curl_close($crl);
        return $ret;
}`

Comment: Ok. For what I am seeing the problem resides basically in the createURL function. In that function you create a few variables that you don't actually use, so can you tell me if this works?
`$test = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=07&b=19&c=2012&d=11&e=08&f=2012&g=d&ignore=.csv';
getCSVFile($test, "memory.txt");`
thanks

Comment: Yes it does work. The problem resides in the way .ticker is concatenated i think. the variables above where initally included in the url but i've deleted their insertion in the URL to simplify things.

Comment: Try replacing your createURL function with this one:
`function createURL($ticker){
    $result = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s='.urlencode($ticker).'&a=07&b=19&c=2012&d=11&e=08&f=2012&g=d&ignore=.csv';
    return $result;
}`